# Mysql query to mysqli query UPDATE statement

Tags: php

Im trying to convert mysql query to mysqli but it doesnt work...why?
From:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE views SET views=views+1 WHERE viewID='1'");
```

To:

```
$q1 = $mysqli->query("UPDATE views SET views=views+1 WHERE viewID='1'");
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

When I do

```
mysqli_query("UPDATE views SET views=views+1 WHERE viewID='1'");
```

> mysqli_query expects two parameters

Comment: What happens when you do `mysqli_query("UPDATE views SET views=views+1 WHERE viewID='1'");`. Further i suggest you go through PDO

Comment: Might want to start your work with `mysqli_` (kudos for going there!) by reading [the guide on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)

Comment: Well, first off you need to create a `mysqli` instance (in your `$mysqli` variable) using `$mysqli = mysqli_connect(...)` or `$myslqi = new mysqli(...)`

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have not initialized MySqli object named `$mysqli`. There are 2 ways of doing that

**Procedural**

If you want it to do Procedural way you would do it like this

```
$q1 = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE views SET views=views+1 WHERE viewID=1");
```

Where `$connection` is the result of `mysqli_connect`, like this

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
```

**OOP**

If you want to do it the OOP way, you would need to initialize your `$mysqli` like this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");
```

And then you can query like

```
$q1=$mysqli->query("UPDATE views SET views=views+1 WHERE viewID=1");
```

**[Manual](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query)**

Comment: and in case it causes any confusion, where Hanky has "world", that is the *db_name* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

@Ron Manuela, First Create Object of mysqli by below way & then use that object so your error would be resolved :)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
```

After creation of object you can write your query as below :

```
$q1=$mysqli->query("UPDATE views SET views=views+1 WHERE viewID='1'");
```

Let me know if still any issues.

Comment: VOTE UP REQUIRES 15 REPUTATION?

Comment: @RonManuela Yes I guess.